# How can I pull Planner information from the Microsoft Graph API and insert the data into my C#.NET Windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm working on a project where I have to get tasks inside of Microsoft Planner from the Microsoft Graph API and then load the tasks and their information into a grid in a C#.NET Windows form. The only direction I've been given is to use Microsoft Power Automation, but I'm completely new to all of these Microsoft Programs. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Planner API in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/planner-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) to create and list tasks. Please see [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planner-post-plans?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request) on adding the .Net SDK to your project, creating an authProvider instance and creating a task.

Please let me know if this helps, and if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps. The only other question I have is what my type of authorization would be for a Windows form? Would that just be a desktop app?